# Part of UIButton stops responding to touch after having its height increased

Tags: uibutton, constraints

I have a view, embedded into a container that it itself inside a UIScrollView.
This view contains a text aligned to its edges as well as a button, again aligned to edges.
When launching the controller view, inside viewDidLayoutSubviews, I get the actual real height of the screen, then I call the view to be resized this way :

```
- (void)viewDidLayoutSubviews {

    [self log:@"ViewDidLayoutSubviews"];

    //::.. change scroll height according to main view ..::
    float mainHeight = _subMainView.frame.size.height;
    float scrollHeight = mainHeight - _scrollView.frame.origin.y;
    _scrollView.frame = CGRectMake(_scrollView.frame.origin.x, _scrollView.frame.origin.y, _scrollView.frame.size.width, scrollHeight);

    //::.. find buttons in child ..::
    UIViewController *child = [self.childViewControllers lastObject];

    //::.. Get only block views ::..
    NSArray *blockViews = [myTools getAllSubviewsFromView:child.view ofClass:[UIView class] byTagFrom:1000 toTag:1010];
    [self resizeViews:blockViews intoFrame:_scrollView.frame withVerticalPadding:16.0f andTopMargin:(31.0f+16.0f) andBottomMargin:0.0f andLeftMargin:16.0f andRightMargin:16.0f];

    NSArray *buttons = [myTools getAllSubviewsFromView:child.view ofClass:[UIButton class]];
    [self resizeViews:buttons intoFrame:_scrollView.frame withVerticalPadding:16.0f andTopMargin:(31.0f+16.0f) andBottomMargin:0.0f andLeftMargin:16.0f andRightMargin:16.0f];

    for (UIButton *button in buttons) {
        [button invalidateIntrinsicContentSize];
    }
}
```

And here is the resize code in question :

```
+ (void)resizeViews:(NSArray *)views intoFrame:(CGRect)parentFrame withVerticalPadding:(float)verticalPadding andTopMargin:(float)topMargin andBottomMargin:(float)bottomMargin andLeftMargin:(float)leftMargin andRightMargin:(float)rightMargin {

    float blockHeight = ((parentFrame.size.height - topMargin - bottomMargin) / views.count);
    blockHeight -= verticalPadding;
    float origin = topMargin;
    for (UIView *aView in views) {
        [aView layoutIfNeeded];
        for (NSLayoutConstraint *constraint in aView.constraints) {
            if (constraint.firstAttribute == NSLayoutAttributeHeight) {
                constraint.constant = blockHeight;
            break;
            }
        }
        origin += blockHeight + verticalPadding;
        [aView setNeedsUpdateConstraints];
        [aView layoutIfNeeded];
    }
}
```

The visual result is good because both views and there content (the buttons) are correctly resized (the button is aligned centered vertically and horizontally so it is easy to show the good alignment).
However, the first button has is whole area touchable where the second one, under it, can be touched only on its upper height, before its middle...
Can't understand how it is possible that a button, who's size is good, become untouchable on its whole part ?

Any help ? :)
Thanks a lot.